# Get each Attribute of element in loop function

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I have a HTML DIV element:

```
<div class="obj" height="this is attr 1" rel="this is att2" width="this is att3"></div>
```

I've a new Variable: `attArray`:

```
var attArray = new Array();
```

I want to get step by step each att in `div.obj` into `attArray`. How do I do it?

```
attArray[0] = "this is attr1"
attArray[1] = "this is attr2"
attArray[2] = "this is attr3"
```

Comment: If you think that's too hard, maybe you should seriously reconsider your employment.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @Tate.

Comment: Are all you attributes of the form `attr<number>`? Of you wrote that just as an example?

Comment: oh, sorry for my Question.. everyone's begin with zero ^^. i'm learning and i was stacked..

Comment: So you just want to get `attr0`, `attr1`, `attr2` ... ?

Comment: i write my Question with some incorrect.. sorry.

Comment: Overwrote your update with mine, sorry. I have now merged the versions.

Comment: ^^. thankyou :). now Q really clear for everybody :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

```
$('.obj').each(function() {
   var attArray = [];
   for(var k = 0; k < this.attributes.length; k++) {
       var attr = this.attributes[k];
       if(attr.name != 'class')
          attArray.push(attr.value);
   }
   //do something with attArray here...
});
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/tjuFH/3/)

Comment: Why do you assume they have that format? And even so they're 1-indexed, not 0-index as you implemented.

Comment: I see now, but I still think (or like to think) he wants any element attribute (class, id, title, etc.). Otherwise it's plain boring.

Comment: yea.. I forgot somethink.. if in EX: instead 'att1' = 'a' ; 'att2' = e; ' att3 ' = c. How do you resolve this ? TO @Alin : you're right!. :)

Answer (score 4):

Each element already has an attributes-collection, you can access it like an array.