# How to have every attribute's names and values of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to have every attribute's names and values of an element of the DOM using jQuery and JavaScript. I've written this piece of code:

```
$.each(attribute.attributes, function (ident, attrib) {
    alert(attrib.value);
    alert(attrib.name);
});
```

"attribute" is an attribute of the DOM.
I've found .attributes method online but I don't know why the program crashes entering in this function.

Comment: Can you show us how the `attribute`-object looks like?

Comment: Every attribute? I'd probably just do `$("*").each(function() { console.log(this.id); });` -- something about that seems wrong tho.

Comment: possible dupplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645806/get-all-attributes-of-an-element-using-jquery

Comment: If you're doing it for the sake of logging, you can try with console.dir(attribute)... FF (Firebug) and Chrome (F12) will be happy to show you object internals!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.obj').each(function() {
   var attArray = [];
   for(var k = 0; k < this.attributes.length; k++) {
       var attr = this.attributes[k];
       if(attr.name != 'class')
          attArray.push(attr.value);
   }
   alert(attArray[2]); //x = 55
   //do something with attArray here...
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tjuFH/3/

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011671/get-each-attribute-of-element-in-loop-function)

Answer (score 0):

### [**Credits**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14645827/1451422)

### JavaScript

```
$(this).each(function() {
  $.each(this.attributes, function() {
    // this.attributes is not a plain object, but an array
    // of attribute nodes, which contain both the name and value
    if(this.specified) {
      console.log(this.name, this.value);
    }
  });
});
```